# Initialize static member in initialization list

Tags: c++

How do I make `G::t` static? (e.g., `G::t` should be of type `const static int&`) `G::t` is defined by the constructor parameter `p` and not available anywhere else.

```
class G {
public:
    // I want to make this static.
    const int& t;

    G(const int& p);
};

G::G(const int& p) : t(p) {}

int main() {
    int a=2;
    const int& b = a;

    G g = G(b);
}
```

Comment: So why do you want to make it static then?! The question makes no sense.

Comment: Because it is needed by openGL member functions in G that has to be static, and static functions cannot read non static variables

Comment: They can if you pass them a `G*` or a `G&`. I think you have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Can't pass any parameters to those functions, they are glut callbacks; glutdisplayfunc() etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "not available anywhere else"?  Else than where?

Comment: @Hosdgfag2, Do you know what it means for a member to be static?

Answer (score 2):

e.g.:

```
const int a = 10;

class foo
{
    static const constexpr int& t = a;
};
```

You can't initialize static member in constructor, because constructors are for objects, not for class as whole.

Comment: `constexpr` implies `const`, so the `const` is redundant.

Comment: sorry, but: `error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'int&' from expression of type 'const int'
     static constexpr int& t = a;`

Comment: Oh true. The `const` refers to the referenced `int`, while the `constexpr` refers to the reference itself.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you even using a constructor if you want to set static members to be used by static functions? That's not what constructors are for. You definitely can't initialize a static member in an initializer-list, because that would mean it gets initialized every time you construct another object. (Just think about the difference between per-class static data and per-instance data and it should be obvious why the question makes no sense).

You could use a static local, which is initialized on first use so can be initialized at run-time, and then can be accessed by the static member functions:

```
class G {
public:
    static int t(const int& p = 0, bool set = false);

    G(const int& p);
};

G::G(const int& p) { t(p, true); }

int G::t(const int& p, bool set)
{
    static bool is_set = false;
    if (!is_set)
    {
        if (!set)
            throw std::logic_error("Cannot use G::t before it is set");
    }
    else if (set)
        throw std::logic_error("Cannot set G::t more than once");
    static const int tt = p;
    set = true;
    return tt;
}

int main() {
    int a=2;
    const int& b = a;

    G g = G(b);
    int t = G::t();
}
```

But this is a horrible hack, you should think carefully about your design and whether using a constructor is appropriate here, or even if using a class is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The member initializer list can only be used to initialize instance variables, so if `t` is static, you can only *reassign* it in the constructor body.

And because references can't be reassigned, you have to use a pointer. A `reference_wrapper` doesn't work because it would need to be statically initialized (unless you have a global int that you can use for that).

E.g.

```
class G {
public:
    static const int* t;

    G(const int& p);
};

const int* G::t; // definition in .cpp

G::G(const int& p) {
    t = &p;
}
```